# Brick documentation guide

Tags: haskell, haskell-brick

I'm trying to make an application using the Brick library and I'm following the official documentation listed here

https://github.com/jtdaugherty/brick/blob/master/docs/guide.rst

I'm on the part making an application state using an editor and I'm following the guide where but am getting an out of scope error when trying to make an application state that uses an editor. Brick has been pretty tough to pick up so far does anyone else have any documentation they recommend reading or following to get a hang of it?

I tried

data MyState = MyState { _editor :: Editor Text n }
makeLenses ''MyState

but am getting an out of scope error on n.

Comment: `data MyState n = MyState { _editor :: Editor Text n }`?

Comment: thats what I thought too so it is just a problem in the documentation?

Comment: Probably just a typo.

Comment: cref: https://github.com/jtdaugherty/brick/pull/495